# Task is not created when the Opportunity is newly created or edited using Process Builder, why?

Tags: apex, process-builder

I am facing an issue in the Process Builder which seems not creating a task. I checked the logs, but I dont see error or exceptions, not sure what is going wrong.

```
Criteria Name : Closed Won and Banking
Criteria for Executing Actions* : Conditions are met
```

When these condition matches

[image]

I expect the task should be created.

[image]

**The error logs:**

```
04:05:21.0 (339376)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Opportunity:new
04:05:21.0 (352956)|VALIDATION_RULE|03d7F000000c2u2|Close_Date_Alert
04:05:21.0 (554391)|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AND( NOT(IsClosed),  CloseDate < TODAY())|IsClosed=1 , CloseDate=2017-06-30 00:00:00
04:05:21.0 (565450)|VALIDATION_PASS
04:05:21.0 (619786)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Opportunity:new
04:05:21.0 (626643)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
04:05:21.26 (26162025)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0057F000000l2bg|XXXXXXXXX@xy.com|Pacific Standard Time|GMT-07:00
04:05:21.26 (26182497)|EXECUTION_STARTED
04:05:21.26 (26185073)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Opportunity
04:05:21.26 (34711111)|WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN|Workflow
04:05:21.26 (34799048)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Opportunity: Cool Opportunity 0067F000002VVmZ]|Workflow_Rule_Migration3017F0000008hEE|01Q7F000000c1Dm|ON_ALL_CHANGES|0
04:05:21.26 (35100462)|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull]true|Values:
04:05:21.26 (35114668)|WF_CRITERIA_END|true
04:05:21.26 (35613078)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Opportunity: Cool Opportunity 0067F000002VVmZ]|Opportunity_Management3017F0000008hBK|01Q7F000000c1DN|ON_ALL_CHANGES|0
04:05:21.26 (35667724)|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull]true|Values:
04:05:21.26 (35678230)|WF_CRITERIA_END|true
04:05:21.26 (35702395)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Workflow
04:05:21.26 (35729676)|WF_ACTION| Flow Trigger: 2;
04:05:21.26 (35734565)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
04:05:21.26 (36344216)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_BEGIN|09L7F0000004RSy
04:05:21.37 (37149035)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D7F0000001I8v|3007F000000Cgdw|3017F0000008hBK
04:05:21.37 (39135702)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|2380b2ae6b382419be8136ff483e15cf89cae9f-2699|Opportunity Management
04:05:21.39 (39503742)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN|1
04:05:21.39 (39545464)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|2380b2ae6b382419be8136ff483e15cf89cae9f-2699|Opportunity Management
04:05:21.39 (41983953)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|2380b2ae6b382419be8136ff483e15cf89cae9f-2699|Opportunity Management
04:05:21.39 (76012467)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_END|1
04:05:21.26 (77045549)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_END|09L7F0000004RSy
04:05:21.26 (77086601)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_BEGIN|09L7F0000004RTD
04:05:21.77 (77173295)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D7F0000001I8v|3007F000000Cghy|3017F0000008hEE
04:05:21.77 (79269613)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|2381b2ae6b382419be8136ff483e15cf89cae9f-2698|Workflow Rule Migration3
04:05:21.79 (79552476)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN|1
04:05:21.79 (79594908)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|2381b2ae6b382419be8136ff483e15cf89cae9f-2698|Workflow Rule Migration3
04:05:21.79 (83024668)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|2381b2ae6b382419be8136ff483e15cf89cae9f-2698|Workflow Rule Migration3
04:05:21.96 (96506740)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|APXTConga4
04:05:21.96 (101300020)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[46]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id, APXTConga4__WhatId__c FROM APXTConga4__Conga_Email_Staging__c 
04:05:21.96 (105137612)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[46]|Rows:0
04:05:21.105 (105810471)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
04:05:21.105 (105810471)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
```

When the opportunity is created, I dont see any task is created under the related list. Any idea ?

Added screen shots for reference. Note: HDFC Account has Industry Type as Banking.

[image]

Comment: How do you link your task to the opportunity? We can't see it on your picture.

Comment: oh. I got it. Are you saying that Related To ID -> Reference -> [Opportunity].Id - This works

Comment: Exactly ! This is what you needed.